# Random string generation producing weird characters

Tags: c++, string, random

My random string generation is generating a random string from the chars a-z just fine, but at the end of it, there's some weird characters: `ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ`. Also, after the weird characters, it prints `a-z` again.

```
    if( m_lower.GetCheck() == 1 )
{
    char pwd[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char password[26];
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++) {
    password[i] = pwd[rand()%26];
    }
    OnGenerate = password;
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

The above code checks to see if the checkbox is checked, then it sends the random text to an edit control. Which almost works fine, it's just the weird characters, and extra `a-z` at the end. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You didn't show us the code where you output anything. Kind of important... Almost certainly this is due to not null-terminating your C-string. Why don't you use `std::string`?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to append a null terminator at the end of the string.

```
password[sizeof(password) - 1] = '\0'; //note sizeof works in this case because 
                                       //password is an array and sizeof(char)==1
```

(you'll need to modify the size of `password` to 27 and fill in the first 26 characters with random ones)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley meant to write sizeof.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is C++ and not C, you should take advantage of `std::string`:

```
if( m_lower.GetCheck() == 1 )
{
    char pwd[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    std::string password;
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++) {
        password.append(1, pwd[rand() % 26]);
    }
    OnGenerate = password.c_str();
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

Thus eliminating any need to explicitly keep track of string terminator. Since password variable will go out of scope at the end of the `if` block, if `OnGenerate` is a `char*`, then you will end up having a **dangling pointer**. Using the `string` directly, assures that the content is kept alive:

```
if( m_lower.GetCheck() == 1 )
{
    char pwd[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    OnGenerate.clear();
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++) {
        OnGenerate.append(1, pwd[rand() % 26]);
    }
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

You should declare `OnGenerate` to be of type `std::string` instead of `char*`. You can access the  `char*` if neeeded with `OnGenerate.c_str()`.

Comment: All in favor of using C++ concepts, but what'd happen to `OnGenerate` when `password` goes out of scope?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore The same that will happen to the `OnGenerate` var in the OP's code and with your update too, I guess ;)

Comment: Hmmmm, you might be onto something :) @user3179762 make sure you don't use `OnGenerate` after the scope of `password` (whichever type it is) ends. It'll be a dangling pointer.

Comment: Updated the answer with a fix.

Comment: What makes either of you believe that `OnGenerate` is a pointer, rather than a `std::string`? In which case, there is nothing wrong with the assignment, or using `OnGenerate` after the lifetime of `password`.